# Color segmentation (finding cells in an image)

Tags: colors, cell, image-segmentation

I'm trying to find red cells on a green background. I have tried already a few methods (RGB, HSV...) but I'm struggling with very light red cells. The best method up to now is to take the RGB values and set the highest value to 255 and the rest to 0, e.g. if (167, 20, 63) -> (255, 0, 0). However this is risky and do not work very well with light cells. Can anyone help with some methods hints? I attached an example.

Edit: There is no need to find the cells, only a pixel number value is enough.

Any help is very appreciated!

Stefanie

[image: Cell]

[image]

Comment: I might be able to assist a bit. Is this question still relevant?
Do you have training data (i.e., few labeled images)? Can you assume something about size and/or shape of cells? I believe you can gain a lot from using *semantic segmentation* based on training data.

Comment: Hi! I would appreciate it a lot! I tried different things with colors but no success. I can generate a set of training data. How many would you suggest? And yes the cells are defined by size and shape (both). Thank you very much for mentioning semantic segmentation, I'll read about it. If you have any suggestion, I would be very happy because the problem is still not solved!

Comment: first stage: try and learn **soft** classifier for the red cells. Try visualizing the images in different color spaces: RGB, HSV, Lab. train an SVM classifier to separate the red cells. DO NOT EXPECT PERFECT RESULTS. but it should be far from random...

Comment: How proficient you are with C++? You can do a lot with DTF: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/03e0ca05-8aa9-49f6-801f-bb23846dc147/

Comment: I tried different color spaces, HSV performed the best and it worked very well on the image above. But some images have red-brown spots and they are also recognized and introduce a big error. Do you mean to train on those HSV image? How many images for training are realistic? I have no idea from such things, do we talk about 10,100 or 1000? I'm not familiar with C++, I'm actually not really a programmer, just use Python for private projects.

Comment: I'm afraid this is going beyond the scope of SO Q&A... you'll have to know some C++ or matlab... I suggest you read some about semantic segmentation: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~dana/readingMedIm/papers/CRF_TextonBoost_ECCV2006.pdf is a good starting point

Comment: Thanks Shai for your help. I think it will be a rather large project but it is good to know where to start.

Comment: if you manage to set it up properly, I think DTF would be a good choice for getting cutting-edge algorithm to work for your advantage.

Comment: Is this question still relevant? How many the red cells in this image? 1 or 13? Can you circle this red cells on image?

Comment: Hi Pylyp! This question is still relevant. There are about 10 cells in this image. You can see them in different size between the stripes of the leaf (transport tissue).

Comment: I uploaded an image with the labeled cells.